# <a> tag's href showing different url on hover

Tags: html, reactjs, url, dom, hyperlink

In a React component I want to show a link. That link's url comes from props. In a browser dev tool  tag's href shows correct url but on hover it shows something different. Actually it's a combination of my project main url and the url I want to show. On click it tries to got to that combined url and shows error. I console logged and the url coming to the component via props is correct. Doex

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do assign your URL with `http://` or `https://` otherwise it will consider it as the local directory from your project.

Something like this:

```
<a href="http://mail.ru"></a>
```